# Add information from another table to a mysql-query-result by an id with a JOIN - MYSQL

Tags: mysql

My tablestructure looks like this:

**job**

```
| jobuniqueid | jobtypeunique | jobdateadded | jobtitle | jobuserkey | jobdeleted
|      1      |       3       | 2019-04-04   | Dentist  |    69      |    0
```

**jobtype**

```
| jobtypeunique | jobtypename | jobtypecolor |
|       3       | fulltime    |   #336699    |
```

So, I want to do a query which shows me the following information per row:

**jobuniqueid**, **jobdateadded**, **jobtitle**, **jobtypename**, **jobtypecolor**

I try to realize this with a leftjoin, like this:

```
SELECT jobunique, jobdateadded, jobtitle FROM job 
WHERE (jobuserkey = 69 AND jobdeleted = 0) 
LEFT JOIN jobtype ON job.jobtypeunique = jobtype.jobtypeunique 
ORDER BY jobdateadded DESC
```

This query results in a bunch of errors. Can you explain to me where my syntax is false - and, where do I declare which colums I would like to show from the **jobtype**-table.

Comment: These key words have to be in the proper order (listed) and with the proper syntax following: SELECT, FROM, JOINS, WHERE, GROUP BY, HAVING, ORDER BY, LIMIT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```
SELECT j.jobuniqueid, j.jobdateadded, j.jobtitle, jt.jobtypename, jt.jobtypecolor
FROM job j LEFT JOIN jobtype jt ON j.jobtypeunique = jt.jobtypeunique 
WHERE j.jobuserkey = 69 AND j.jobdeleted = 0
ORDER BY j.jobdateadded DESC
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d615a2136f5792cf0610227ce32c1ab0)

You have to use the `WHERE` part after the `FROM ... LEFT JOIN ... ON ...`. The `FROM` and `LEFT JOIN` part is defining a new (joined) table. After the `FROM` and `LEFT JOIN` part you can use `WHERE` to filter the rows of the joined tables. Also have a look at the [documentation of `SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html).

Comment: I got a little problem with the code. My mysql server throws this error: " Unknown column 'j.jobuniqueid' in 'field list'" - What looks to me, that the server doesn´t understand the aliases. My Mysql server runs on version 5.7

Comment: Ah, everythings fine. there was a typo, sorry